# Fractals created by point moving inside polygon

Tags: geometry, fractals, polygons

I'm looking at fractals created by a point moving inside a polygon with *vx* vertices. The point chooses a vertex at random and then jumps *a*/*b* of the distance towards it. For example, if *vx* = 3 and *a*/*b* = 1/2, the point creates the Sierpinski triangle, i.e. a 3-ring of contingent triangles, each of which is a 3-ring of contingent triangles, etc.

If *vx* = 5 and *a*/*b* = 1/φ (I think), the point creates a 5-ring of contingent pentagons, etc. You can see the 5-ring at this link (the colors simply record how many times a pixel has been visited by the moving point):

[Pentagonal ring](https://postimg.org/image/awnrnl2cl/)

If *vx* = 6 and *a*/*b* = 2/3, the points creates a 6-ring of contingent hexagons, etc:

[Hexagonal ring](https://postimg.org/image/al6batlwl/)

If *a*/*b* doesn't take these values, the polygons aren't contingent, i.e. they overlap or fail to touch at all.

My question is: what is the formula to derive *a*/*b* from *vx* to create the required *vx*-ring?

Comment: As you may know, the iterative process you describe is known as the Chaos Game. See entries on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChaosGame.html).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the term "chaos game", but should have.

Answer (score 5):

Bob Strichartz provides a formula on page 323 of [this paper](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/AMM/evaluatingintegrals.pdf):

$$\frac{\sin \left(\pi/n\right)}{\sin \left(2 \pi 
   \left\lfloor n/4\right\rfloor/n+\pi/n\right)+
\sin \left(\pi/n\right)}.$$

The first dozen values are

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n & r(n) & \approx \\
\hline
 2 & 1/2 & 0.5 \\
\hline
 3 & 1/2 & 0.5 \\
\hline
 4 & 1/2 & 0.5 \\
\hline
 5 & \frac{2}{3+\sqrt{5}} & 0.381966 \\
\hline
 6 & 1/3 & 0.333333 \\
\hline
 7 & \frac{2}{2+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{14}\right)} & 0.307979 \\
\hline
 8 & \frac{1}{1+\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)} & 0.292893 \\
\hline
 9 & \frac{2}{2+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)} & 0.257773 \\
\hline
 10 & \sqrt{5}-2 & 0.236068 \\
\hline
 11 & \frac{2}{2+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{22}\right)} & 0.221566 \\
\hline
 12 & \frac{1}{6} \left(3-\sqrt{3}\right) & 0.211325 \\
\hline
 13 & \frac{2}{2+\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{26}\right)} & 0.194246 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Leading to the following sequence of images:
[image]

Comment: you seem to be the fractal expert. Always providing excellent answers!

Comment: @Kuifje Thanks! I think it's safe to say I am *a* fractal expert - though, there are others around including my PhD advisor. I do like answering interesting questions and keep my eyes peeled for fractal stuff in particular.

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. I suspected the formula was way above my pay-grade and I was right.